# Initilize a vector of Pair<int,int> with emplace_back

Tags: c++

I want to initialize a vector of integer pairs while specifying its size (I have to use this structure). I tried:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> container;
container.emplace_back(size);
```

And:

```
container.emplace_back(size, make_pair(0, 0));
```

But I keep having this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<int, int>::pair(long long unsigned int&, std::pair<int, int>)'
```

Is there any solution or different approach?

Thank you!

Comment: emplace back does not take a size parameter. What do you expect `container.emplace_back(size, make_pair(0, 0));` to do?

Comment: I'm planning to put elements (pair of int) inside using a loop

Answer (score 3):

`emplace_back` forwards its parameters to the elements constructor. `std::pair<int,int>` has no constructor that takes a size and a pair, hence the error. To emplace an element:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> container;
container.emplace_back(0,0);
```

However, if you want to construct a vector of certain size upfront, you need not emplace elements, because they are already there:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> container(size);
container[42] = make_pair(1,2);   // 42 < size   !
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm ***guessing*** what you really want is something like:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> container(size);
```

This will initialize the vector `constainer` with `size` number of default-constructed elements.

Comment: My bad! I forgot to specify that size is a variable that I will have, not default one

Comment: @StayAlone Doesn't matter if `size` is a variable or a compile-time constant. It works equally well.